# ng-repeat filter with OR condition of property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanted to filter a list with a model value from the text box.

Example

```
 var person={};
 person.Id=1;
 person.Name="Test 1";
 person.PetName="Rest 1"

 var persons=[];
 persons.push(person);

 person.Id=2;
 person.Name="Test ds";
 person.PetName="Rest sd";
 persons.push(person);
```

Persons array will have multiple persons.
In HTML I have one search box.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="seachText" placeholder="search by Name and pet name"/>

<div ng-repeat="person in persons | filter : {$:seachText}">
<div>{{person.Name}}</div>
</div>
```

Case 1:

When I enter 2 in the text box, one result will appear. I don't want that.
I want to filter by name and pet-name only.

Is there any possibility to achieve this without a custom filter?
Does filter directive allow OR condition for properties?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: `persons` will have two identical objects because you're making changes in and pushing the same object twice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216115/filtering-by-multiple-specific-model-properties-in-angularjs-in-or-relationship

Comment: No.. am re using same object. Anyways thats not an issue. Assume an array with multiple records and you have to search with few property with same model value

Comment: Thanks Marcus, that will work, but it is custom filter

Answer (score 1):

For me [custom "OR" filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506826/filter-by-multiple-fields-in-ionic/48537502#48537502) is preferred solution, nevertheless you can use built-in `filter` two times(for each OR condition) and then UNION <strike>ALL</strike> results:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.persons = [
    {Id:95, Name:"Tom", PetName: "Pet1"},
    {Id:96, Name:"Sam", PetName: "Pet2"},
    {Id:97, Name:"Max", PetName: "Pet3"},
    {Id:98, Name:"Henry", PetName: "Pet4"}
  ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <input type='text' ng-model='search'/>
  <div ng-repeat='person in temp = (persons | filter : {Name: search})'>
    {{person | json}}
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat='person in persons | filter : {PetName: search}' ng-if='temp.indexOf(person) == -1'>
    {{person | json}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks :) I was just looking for answer whether OR condition exists within inbuilt filter. I guess not, so I have taken custom filter approach.